# How to check if there are two identical objects in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So I have an array and I want to know whether there are two identical elements.

My first thought was of a `O(n^2)` algorithm where I compare each element with all the others but of course it's not optimal.

My second thought was of sorting the array and then just comparing the neighbouring elements but it doesn't sound like the perfect solution.

I guess I can only dream of `O(n)` but is there a faster way in at least `O(n*log(n))` to do it? (Of course, I would very much appretiate an `O(n)` solution.

EDIT: I have to do this as a part of a more complex algorithm so I am going to have to make a new array and get the answer `n*log(n)` times so I don't feel like hashing.

Comment: sorting yields `O(n log n)`...

Comment: Ο(n) is obvious (hashing) but it needs extra space. O(nlogn) is the best you can do without extra space.

Comment: Yeah Jan I know its nlogn but I was wondering if there was another way that maybe yields smaller constants because this is a bit on the edge of my time limit

Comment: It all comes down to what the objects stored in the array are.

Comment: Also, maybe we can help you better if you tell us the "complex algorithm" which you need to optimize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically the **[element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem)**, which cannot be solved better than `O(nlogn)`, unless you are exploiting a hashing solution with addition space.